# Apple TV - Not able to input text using keyboard after updating to tvos10

Tags: xcode, apple-tv, tvos10

After updating the appleTV OS to tvOS 10, I am not able to select any of the previously used emails/ password values from the keyboard which shows up on clicking the textfield. Add new is not clickable too. Please suggest if this is a known bug?

Comment: Can you add some code please?

Comment: It is a normal textfield of type email. Please see the screenshot for the properties.